# Font setting on Python IDLE is not being applied properly

Tags: python, fonts, size, python-idle

I was trying to enlarge the font size of Python IDLE (I'm currently using Python 2.7.12, 32 bit, on Windows 10, 64 bit), so I entered the option menu as I used to do on my previous laptop and changed the font size from 10 to 14.

However, even though I surely clicked on 'Apply' and 'OK' buttons, nothing has changed. Despite several trials, the font size keeps returning to the default setting, 10. I also tried it after restarting IDLE.

While searching for the solution, I read that by modifying some statements of `idlelib.ConfigDialog.py` user can change some settings related to the font size. Thus I even tried like below, but failed.

```
# Original one
'''
self.optMenuFontSize.SetMenu(('7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13',
                              '14', '16', '18', '20', '22'), fontSize )
'''
# Modified one
self.optMenuFontSize.SetMenu(('14', '16', '18', '20', '22'), fontSize )
```

Anyone struggled with the same problem?

++ 
I added wildly different font size on `idlelib.ConfigDialog.py` like 40, but didn't work well. There exists 40 on the font size list, but whenever I select 40, click OK, and restart IDLE, nothing happens nor any log appears on the console.

++
As one of the commenter said, I started IDLE from Command Prompt and the results were not different from what I got previously. I also took a look at file named `config-main.cfg` and find out that all the other user settings like indentation width or whatever changed properly, only except options about FONT.

I even tried adding `[EditorWindow] font-size= 16` on `config-main.cfg`, but did not work either. It just keeps turning back to default setting.

Just to be sure, my laptop is for personal use and I installed Python for All Users.

Comment: Try a wildly different font size e.g. 40pt, just to see if it sticks. Maybe it is testing whether a specific size exists before allowing it, and it is determining that the 14pt size doesn't exist. Also, does IDLE have any logs you can look at?

Comment: I am the current IDLE maintainer and this report is new for me (and I also have Win 10 and can run both 32 and 64 bit pythons).  To try to diagnose, first start IDLE from Command Prompt with `python -m idlelib.idle` or `py -2.7 -m idlelib.idle`.  Are there any messages displayed on the console, especially when you try to change font size size.  Second, look at `C:/Users/Jihye` (or whatever name you login as).  Is there `.idlerc`?  If so, what files does it contain?  The most important for this isue is probably `config-main.cfg`.  If present, what does it contain?

Comment: Also, is this your personal machine or an institutional (school) machine?  Did you install for All Users? or just one user?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy First of all, I really appreciate your detail diagnosis in several ways. 
About your first suggestion, I tried both way to start IDLE from Command Prompt and no message was shown on the console when I tried to change the font size. Secondly, I have a folder named '.idlerc' in 'C:/Users/Jihye', and it contains only 2 files: 'breakpoints.lst' and 'recent-files.lst'. There was no file named 'config-main.cfg' in my computer. And the last one, this is my personal machine and I think I installed it for All Users. Can the missing file 'config-main.cfg' cause a trouble like this?

Comment: @halfer I tried that but didn't work well. There is 40 on the font size list, and whenever I select 40, click OK, and restart IDLE, nothing happens nor any log appears on the console.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I made a change on indentation width and then `config-main.cfg` appears. This indentation settings changed properly. I think it's only the font that IDLE has trouble with. I added some statements in `config-main.cfg` like this `[EditorWindow] font-size= 16`
but still not working. It just keeps turning back to default setting. Should I try uninstalling it?

Comment: @halfer You got a good point. Done with that :) Thanks.

Comment: config-main.cfg is written by IDLE when and only when there are custom settings.  It should have been written when you tried to change font size.  As you noted, it was when you changed the indent.  What about the font choice?  Or the initial editor window size?  The entries have the same format as idlelib/config-main.def, except that the values are not the default values.  The user config files can also be edited by hand, though mistakes can be a problem, and the best solution is sometimes to erase the file.  We now know that inability to write the file is not the problem.

Comment: Did you install 2.7 with the python.org installer or something else.  If you have the original python.org installer (or re-download), I believe if you run it, it will notice the current installation and offer the option to 'repair'.  I believe this basically means to reinstall with the current options.  IE, recopy the files.